# How to check if pointer address has the value 0xffffffffffffffff (i.e., is pointing to the maximum address)?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, c99

I am trying to dereference a pointer to an `unsigned char*`, but the program crashes with segfault because its value is always 0xffffffffffffffff. Before dereferencing the pointer, I would like to check whether it is pointing address is different than 0xffffffffffffffff (to avoid segfaults). How could I check that without hardcoding the check against 0xffffffffffffffff ? i.e.,

```cpp
unsigned char* pointer;
...

// I would rather use something which works for x86 or x64 machine
if( pointer & 0xffffffffffffffff >= 0xffffffffffffffff - 1 ) {
    // exit
}
```

I was researching and I found this https://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.1/dinkum_en/c99/stdint.html#UINTPTR_MAX, but that UINTPTR_MAX seems to be the maximum value of the integer the pointer is pointing to, other than the maximum value of the pointer address.

The problem is consistent, every segmentation fault, the pointer has the value 0xffffffffffffffff.
[image]

I know I should fix my application so the pointer is not set to the invalid address  0xffffffffffffffff, but the code base is quite big and complex and I not sure how to reproduce the problem yet. So, while do not figure out how this pointer is set to an invalid address, I would like to put a protection.

Just out of idle curiosity, how can I purposefully make a pointer to an `unsigned char*` point to the address `0xffffffffffffffff` (maximum address on the target machine) ? My program is doing this somewhere, but I have no idea how as I am still searching for the culprit.

Comment: Sounds like a totally XY-problem. You need to find out why it is getting this value, not try patch it up.

Comment: This looks like you're trying to hide a bug with a hacky solution. You should figure out what the real issue of this problem is. All you should really be checking is that pointer != NULL.

Comment: did you initialize the pointer that is getting this error?

Comment: Make use of the tools available to you to find the root cause instead of trying to put in a kludge. Otherwise it will just blow up somewhere else. There are tools like valgrind, crt debugging, data watch points, etc which can be used to help debug memory problems like this.

Comment: This just an workaround for a behavior my application is having (setting the value 0xffffffffffffffff to address of the pointer). Of course, the definition solution is to find out where the pointer is being set to 0xffffffffffffffff and fix it. This error of setting the pointer to 0xffffffffffffffff is random and only happens after the application is running for several days with millions of requests processed.

Comment: One of the reasons could be a decrement of a NULL pointer. You can use the same for your purpose. Of course, technically it is undefined behavior, but since we are already there, it won't break much further: https://ideone.com/pnKb2r

Comment: This address looks very like `-1` cast to 64-bit unsigned integer. This value is equal to `MAP_FAILED` returned from unsuccessful `mmap()` call. It looks that file mapping failed and error was not handled correctly

Comment: @EugeneSh., thanks for the NULL pointer tip. I did not thought about that. `unsigned char *p = (1 << sizeof(char*) * 8) - 1` seems to work too: https://ideone.com/0F1Mf9 , would it not rely on undefined behavior ? @tstanisl thanks for sharing about the mmap return value MAP_FAILED! Good to know.

Comment: Comparing with `(unsigned char *)-1` should work in practically all situations (though of course none of this will be blessed by the C standard).  `-1` is likely to be handled by the rules of two's complement arithmetic and converted to the largest possible value.  Comparing with `(unsigned char *)UINTPTR_MAX` would work too.

Comment: Re “UINTPTR_MAX seems to be the maximum value of the integer the pointer is pointing to”: `UINTPTR_MAX` is the maximum value the `uintptr_t` type can represent. It has no semantic relationship with whatever is pointed to and equals `(uintptr_t) -1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Casting `-1` to an `unsigned char *` will, on a typical compiler, produce a pointer value of either `0xffffffff` or `0xffffffffffffffff` on a 32-bit or 64-bit system respectively.

```
if (pointer == (unsigned char *)-1) {
    log_msg("The notorious 0xffffffff bug has surfaced!  Details follow...");
    log_msg(/* more info about the program state */);
    abort();
}
```

Other possibilities would include `if (pointer == (unsigned char *)UINTPTR_MAX)` or `if ((uintptr_t)pointer == UINTPTR_MAX)`.

> UINTPTR_MAX seems to be the maximum value of the integer the pointer is pointing to

That's not right.  It's the maximum value of the unsigned integer type `uintptr_t`, which will normally be a 32- or 64-bit integer according to the size of a pointer on this system.  So you can get the desired pointer by casting this value to a pointer, or cast the pointer to `uintptr_t` and compare with `UINTPTR_MAX`.

---

Caveats for future readers: This is only appropriate for the specific case OP mentions: where you have already identified `0xffffffff` etc as the values produced by some specific bug that you are trying to track down.  In general, it is not possible to test at runtime whether a given pointer points to a valid object or not; you have to design your program so that only valid pointers are used in the first place.

Also, any time you talk about a pointer that doesn't point to a specific object (and is not NULL), you are outside the realm of standard C, so all of this is undefined behavior per the standard (or at best implementation-defined behavior).  You are reliant on the behavior of your particular compiler, but it's reasonable to expect them to handle this case in the "natural" way.

Answer (score -1):

Please do not use this, see comments for reference:

> `sizeof(char *) * 8` is likely 32 or 64. Then `1 << sizeof(char*) * 8` is `1 << 32` or `1 << 64`. `1` is an `int` constant, which is likely 32 bits. Then `1 << 32` and `1 << 64` are not defined by the C standard; shifts with widths greater than or equal to the width of the left operand (after promotion) are not defined. And there is no need for any of this; `UINTPTR_MAX` is the value OP asks for (even if their approach is bad), and, if that were unavailable, `(uintptr_t) -1` is also the value.

<s>I did this test program and it seems to be working: https://ideone.com/bqgUrH</s>

```
On if 1
On if 2
1 0xffffffffffffffff
2 0xfffffffffffffffd
```

It takes the size of the `char *` (usually 4 bytes on x86) and multiplies by 8 to convert it to bits (`32 bits`), then, it shifts `1 << 32`, and subtracts 1 making it `0xffffff...`

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned char *p = (1 << sizeof(char*) * 8) - 1;
    unsigned char *p2 = (1 << sizeof(char*) * 8) - 3;

    if (  ((unsigned int)p & ((1 << sizeof(char*) * 8) - 1)) >= ((1 << sizeof(char*) * 8) - 2)  )
    {
        printf("On if 1\n");
    }

    if (!(((unsigned int)p2 & ((1 << sizeof(char*) * 8) - 1)) >= ((1 << sizeof(char*) * 8) - 2)))
    {
        printf("On if 2\n");
    }

    printf("1 %p\n", p);
    printf("2 %p\n", p2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(char *) * 8` is likely 32 or 64. Then `1 << sizeof(char*) * 8` is `1 << 32` or `1 << 64`. `1` is an `int` constant, which is likely 32 bits. Then `1 << 32` and `1 << 64` are not defined by the C standard; shifts with widths greater than or equal to the width of the left operand (after promotion) are not defined. And there is no need for any of this; `UINTPTR_MAX` is the value OP asks for (even if their approach is bad), and, if that were unavailable, `(uintptr_t) -1` is also the value.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, thanks for explaining. Usually, I would delete the answer, but your explanation is good for reference.